# How to convert a System::Char to a C++ char

Tags: c++-cli

I need to convert a System::Char that comes from the .NET world into a char in the C++/CLI world (a native C++ type).

I am confident that the incoming character is a regular ASCII character, just in the .NET Unicode world. So I never will have to deal with a character that doesn't have a direct mapping to char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about converting it directly?

```
System::Char neta = System::Char('b');
char c = neta;
```

Comment: Oh! Since they were really two difference sizes I didn't even think to try this. But it works just fine. How embarrassing! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I have some code working, but it is officially... very ugly. I'm hoping someone else will add an answer to this question that has a better solution than this!

```
// I am given neta externally
System::Char neta = System::Char('b');

// Here is the conversion code - is there a better way?
System::String ^str = gcnew System::String(neta,1);
auto trans = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str->ToString());
auto cstr = static_cast<const char*>(trans.ToPointer());
char c = *cstr;
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(trans);

// c contains the expected answer 'b'.
```

Many thanks!